# How to log out on Mac without sudo?

Tags: macos, command-line, login, non-admin

When I try to log out on a Mac, I often get a message, such and such an application "interrupted logout".  I would like to "force" log out, but I don't have administrative privileges.  Since I don't have administrative privileges, I must go into the command prompt, find the PID of that application, kill the application, and then log out.  This is very time consuming if there are, say, 10 instances of this application running.  Is there an easier way of doing this, short of holding the power button for 5 seconds?

Comment: How do you initially try logging out?  Using the logout option under the Apple menu?

Comment: Yes, that's how.

Comment: `killall(1)` is your friend.

Comment: @Spiff `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '1'`

Comment: @Alex Oh, sorry I was unclear. I was using an old Unix greybeard shorthand expression "commandName(n)", which means "the command named *commandName*, whose documentation can be found in section *n* of the Unix manual. Section 1 of the Unix manual is where all the command-line commands useful to all users (not just administrators) are documented. So since `killall` is useful to all users, it's documented in section 1.